# Proof of the existence of generating polynomials of an ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I'm going through Shilov's *Linear Algebra*, and I've come to the chapter on canonical representations of linear operators, which uses polynomial algebras to develop the JCF.

The topic of algebras of polynomials is very close to that of polynomial rings, and much of the terminology is the same. So, the point that I'm interested in relates to generating polynomials of ideals:

> *Theorem*. Every ideal $E \neq {0}$ of the algebra of polynomials $\Pi$ is obtained from some polynomial $Q_0(\lambda)$ by multiplication by an arbitrary polynomial $P(\lambda)$.

The proof is given as follows.

> [We] find the nonzero polynomial of lowest degree, say $q$, in the ideal $E$, and denote it by $Q_0(\lambda)$. We then assert that every polynomial $Q(\lambda)\in E$ is of the form $P(\lambda)Q_0(\lambda)$, where $P(\lambda) \in \Pi$. ...

The issue I have with this is the premise that, given a non-empty ideal $E$, we can always find a nonzero polynomial of lowest degree. To be clear, my issue isn't with the concept, but with the formality, i.e. if this proof were given in a formal setting, would it be acceptable?

I think the above can be demonstrated by assigning to every polynomial in $E$ an element $j\in \mathbb{N}$ equal to the degree of the polynomial, then stating that from every sequence (finite or infinite) of natural numbers we can find a smallest element. Is this sufficiently common knowledge that we can consider it evident, while maintaining rigor? At least, in the context of linear algebra and ring theory?

Comment: It might be difficult to order the polynomials to make a "sequence of natural numbers". Luckily, you don't need to: every non-empty _set_ of natural numbers has a smallest element.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue I have with this is the premise that, given a non-empty
> ideal $E$ , we can always find a nonzero polynomial of lowest degree.
> To be clear, my issue isn't with the concept, but with the formality,
> i.e. if this proof were given in a formal setting, would it be
> acceptable?

This premise is fine. If $E$ is nonempty, it has polynomials in it, each polynomial has a natural number as its degree, by the well-ordering principle there is a smallest number among the degrees of polynomials in $E$, and there exists a polynomial of that degree. There is nothing informal here. It would be incredibly pedantic to write out all the details I just did every time to make a simple standard argument like this.